# HQL order by clause doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

```
select r,avg(ur.score) 
from UserResource ur 
join Resource r on ur.resourceId=r.id 
group by ur.resourceId 
order by avg(ur.score) desc
```

The query above should return results in `avg(ur.score)` order, but what I get in fact are in `r.id` order. If I change the query to below which only select `avg(ur.score)` ,the results are in `avg(ur.score)` order.

```
select avg(ur.score) 
from UserResource ur 
join Resource r on ur.resourceId=r.id 
group by ur.resourceId 
order by avg(ur.score) desc
```

Why the `order by` clause in first query doesn't work and how to solve it?

Comment: Why do you have a JPA provider log and you don't read it, when it tells you the SQL invoked, and hence the likely answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with your query and its not the ordering that is the problem.

You are trying to group by a column which is not part of the select statement.
As `ur.resourceId=r.id`, you can try something following:

```
select r.id,avg(ur.score) 
from UserResource ur 
join Resource r on ur.resourceId=r.id 
group by r.id 
order by avg(ur.score) desc
```